# jquery ajax function not posting back to div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have:
support_question.php

```
$('#topic').on('change', function() {  
    var sel = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "support_process.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {info : sel},
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            $( "#divtopic" ).data("topic", sel);
        }
    });
});
```

And further down...

In support_process.php, I have:

```
<?php
   echo $_POST['info'];
?>
```

I'm wondering why my "divtopic" div isn't being filled with the $_POST information.

Comment: What shows in the alert?  And how are you checking that the `data` hasn't been set?

Comment: Are you maybe intending to set the html or text of the div instead of the data?

Comment: if the alert shows the data you should use $( "#divtopic" ).html(data); instead

Comment: The alert() is showing the entire contents of the support_process.php file: "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>..."  The body of all this code shows the data that I want, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.data()` method doesn't set text for the user to see. Use:

```
$( "#divtopic" ).text(data);
```

or if your response includes markup:

```
$( "#divtopic" ).html(data);
```

As an aside, you can get the current value of the dropdown with (as Eddie Monge Jr quite rightly points out), `this.value`. (Or more generally if you don't already have a reference to the element use `$("someSelector").val()` - either way there's no need to use `.find('option:selected')`.)

Further reading:

- [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)
- [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)
- [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: or even better, `this.val`. Why include jQuery if you don't need to and the native code is smaller and faster?

Comment: Thanks for the optimization! I've included that.  I tried $( "#divtopic" ).text(data); and $( "#divtopic" ).html(data); to no avail.  Now I have:   `$.ajax({
     url: "support_process.php",
     type: "POST",
     data: {info : sel},
     success: function(data) {
      $( "#divtopic" ).text(data);
      alert(data);
     }
    });`

Comment: Are you sure you have the id correct? jQuery doesn't complain if you use a selector that doesn't find any elements. Assuming you have the id right and that `alert(data)` shows the text you expect then `.text()` or `.html()` will work.

Comment: Thanks, nnnnnn, you are right, it works! In addition to using the data() method incorrectly, I believe my div was set up correctly.  It's posting the correct data in the div now.  I REALLY appreciate your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

If that really is the response the whole php file, then this should work

```
$('#topic').on('change', function() {
  $.post(
    'support_process.php',
    {info : this.value},
    function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      $("#divtopic").html(data);
    },
    'html'
  );
});
```

as @nnnnnn said, you need to add something that actually display the information to the user like `.html()`.

Also, don't use alert to debug. Use console instead as alert can interrupt things and cause headaches whereas console is more reliable and is built for debugging.

Comment: OMG, you are my hero.  Thank you! :))

Comment: Im betting the answer was the dataType then